# Move data from one table to another every night SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this scenario i have a staging table that contains all the record imported from a XML file .Now i want to move this data based on verification like if the record is already in the other table update the record other wise insert the new record. i want to create a job or scheduler in SQL Server that do this for me every night without using any SSIS packages.

Comment: What type of application you on working is it web or desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement?

Answer (score 1):

SSIS really is an easy way to go with something like this, but if necessary, you can set up a a SQL server agent job. [Take a look at this MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181153.aspx). Basically, write your validation code in a stored procedure, then create a job with a TSQL job step which calls that stored procedure.